# Android How to keep Running the background service when app is killed by user?

Tags: java, android

I want a background service that keeps running always in a background? It is running on some phone but not running on customised OS phones like VIVO, OPPO MIUI etc? Service is Killed on these customised OS phone.
My Code is given below --

```
public class MyService extends Service
{

private static final String TAG = "MyService";


@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    return super.onUnbind(intent);
}


@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    //call to onTaskRemoved
    onTaskRemoved(intent);
    //return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
{
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{

    super.onDestroy();
    int i = 1;
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadCastReceiver.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 5);

    if (alarmManager != null)
    {
        alarmManager.setRepeating(
                AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                60000,
                pendingIntent);
    }

}
@Override public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent)
{
    Log.e("onTaskRemoved", "Called!");
    int i = 1;
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadCastReceiver.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 5);

    if (alarmManager != null)
    {
        alarmManager.setRepeating(
                AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES,
                pendingIntent);
    }


    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);

}}
```

I have written a Broadcast Receiver that wake ups my service for every second but it is not working. My Broadcast Receiver as follows-

```
public class MyBroadCastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    Log.e("MyBroadCastReceiver", "onReceive");

    //if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction()))
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        {
            FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(context));
            Job myJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
                    .setService(MyJobService.class)
                    .setTag("myFCMJob")
                    .build();
            dispatcher.mustSchedule(myJob);
        }
        else
        {
            Intent service = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
            context.startService(service);
        }
    }
}}
```

I have started my service using Alarm Manager and have set the Alarm for every 5 seconds, my MainActivity.java file code is as below ---

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

Button btnStopService;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnStopService = findViewById(R.id.btnStopService);

    //get FirebaseToken
    getToken();

    //start Service
    startService();
    //setReceiver();

    btnStopService.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class);
            stopService(intent);
        }
    });

}


private void getToken()
{
    FirebaseId firebaseId=new FirebaseId();
    String token_firebase=firebaseId.getFireBaseToken();
}


private void startService()
{

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, myIntent, 0);
    Log.e("TAG", "++++++++++222222++++++++");
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    //Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    // calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    //calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);

    Calendar alarmStartTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 5);
    if (now.after(alarmStartTime)) {
        Log.d("Hey","Added a day");
        //alarmStartTime.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }

    if (alarmManager != null) {
        alarmManager.set(
                AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                alarmStartTime.getTimeInMillis(),
                pendingIntent);
    }

    Toast.makeText(this, "Start Alarm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

To keep your service and all your application running even if the phone goes into sleep mode, your service has to call `startForeground()` and show a non dismissable notification. 
It is also convenient to acquire a partial WAKE LOCK.

on your `onStartCommand()`

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, Constants.CHANNEL_NOTIFY_ID)
                    .setContentTitle("the content title")
                    .setContentText("the content text")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.myicon)                      
                    .setOngoing(true); 
               // you can add other options Builder has


            startForeground(1234, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, but i don't want to keep showing a non dismissable notification on Status  Bar of device. It a bad user experience.

Comment: Then it is an indispensable condition in Android. To keep a process in the background a notification must exist. In addition with Android 8 or higher if your service does not show one, Android automatically shows a default one

Comment: But Whatsapp have achieved that solution. Their service is still running once we killed app from our recent apps. Even i force stop the service from application settings, the service is temporary stopped, once the mobile data is ON then service will automatically get started and it wakeup the app and shows the notifications. How it is working? Any Idea?

Comment: No, Whatsapp or Messenger or Facebook don't run on the background but they use Push notifications that wake up the phone. If some service prevent the phone to enter sleep mode then Android forces this service to show a Notification, to advise the user that a background app is draining the battery.

Comment: Actually i have an problem with the FCM push notifications. The notification not received when an app is killed by the user. And for that purpose i  wrote this custom service and broadcast receiver to keep notifications arrived when app is in background mean Killed by user.

Comment: Do you have any solution for this problem?